# How to start a gnome shell and run multiple commands from a script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, terminal, gnome

I'm trying to write a script which launches a Gnome terminal and runs multiple commands. It's used to log serial data through an USB and my final goal is to produce a script which opens several COM ports each on a different shell. All shells must execute:

```
sudo script /logs/deviceX.log
sudo picocom /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -p o | ts "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S10"
```

and leave the shell running. I've verified the commands work ok when entered straight to a terminal so I tried creating an `openPort` script with the 2 commands and used

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./openPort; exec bash"
```

but the terminal only executes the first command and not the second.

I then tried creating a separate script for each command and used

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./openPort1; ./openPort2; exec bash"
```

but I still get the same result.

Is it simply a syntax problem or am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching gnome-terminal using -e instead of -x should work. In your case:

`gnome-terminal -e "./openPort"`

If you want to prevent the terminal window from closing, you need to make sure the script doesn't exit (for example by using `sleep` or by adding a "press for any key" prompt in the end, etc.). If you want an interactive shell after your script finishes, adding `bash -i` in the end should work.

Comment: Thanks that worked. There was also an issue with using `script` because of the way it works. Using `sudo script -a -c 'sudo picocom /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -p o | ts "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S10"' /logs/deviceX.log` did the trick. 
`